# How get all photo albums using graph api

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using below code,

```
   <?php
   $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/album-id/albums?fields=id,name&limit=500";
   $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
   foreach($obj->data as $item) {
    echo "<p>". $item->id . "</p>";
   }
   ?>
```

but i can only retrieve up to 50 albums. Please anyone can help me to fix this problem? i searched on this forum, but i cant find a better solution.

Comment: Try reading this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/albums/

Comment: I have read it but didn't find a solution. BTW thanks for your comment (y).

Comment: Do you mean /user-id/ not /album-id/ ? I would suggest taking a look at the pagination section of the api basics section. You may find a 'since=12345' where 12345 is the published / created date of the 50th album result from the previous request will get you a further 1-50 albums.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2

Comment: I will try it. Thanks for the comment